# STM32 board dependencies

Tags: stm32

I need to upload a code written for STM32F302RCT6 uC but I have stm32f4 type of uC board.

The code has the following dependency:

```
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_hal_conf.h"
```

I am kind of novice in ARM and all I need to upload the code successfully to proceed.
Would these libraries work for an stm32f4 device? Is it backwards supported?

Comment: I really doubt the code will work even if you resolve these specific dependencies. These chips can be different in many other ways.

Comment: How about, would any board starting with STM32F3 would work? (The original is STM32F302RCT6)

Comment: No. These chips have different peripherals, even when having a similar computational core. Moreover, these programs are written for different boards - that is the same pins might be connected to different thing on the board.

Comment: You won't be able to go from F3 to another F3 just by changing some headers, let alone going from F3 to F4. You'll need to go through your code line-by-line and adjust peripherals, drivers, pins, etc. But those headers you listed will probably work for another F3 board, but many other modifications will still be required.

Comment: F3 is mixed signal and it is has more (and less)  features than F4. Without knowing what is supposed to do makes no sense a such porting.